# How do I do inline asp.net code?

Tags: asp.net

I could have sworn it was just <%= Something %>

However it doesnt seem to be working:

```
<cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1"
        TargetControlID="pnlUpdatePeriodDetails" runat="server">
        <Animations>
            <OnUpdating>
               <Parallel duration="0">
                    <ScriptAction Script="onUpdating('divLoadingImage', <%= divDetailsContent.ClientID %>);" />
                    <EnableAction AnimationTarget="btnInvoke" Enabled="false" />                    
                </Parallel>
            </OnUpdating>
            <OnUpdated>
                <Parallel duration="0">
                    <ScriptAction Script="onUpdated('divLoadingImage', <%=divDetailsContent.ClientID %>);" /> 
                    <EnableAction AnimationTarget="btnInvoke" Enabled="true" />
                </Parallel>
            </OnUpdated>
        </Animations>
 </cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

I don't even get intellisense...

Comment: Try to put the code as it is in my answer and then somewhere in the Page_Load event add a DataBind() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem the fact that <%= %> appears as it is in the output? In that case try something like this and see if it works:

```
<ScriptAction Script='<%# "onUpdating('divLoadingImage', '" 
   + divDetailsContent.ClientID + "');" %>' />
```

This will need a DataBind on the control or page.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by databind? I get an error with that code alone saying The animations property doesn't allow child objects...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just define a javascript function first, then in the ScriptAction to call it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function update()
  {
      onUpdated('divLoadingImage', <%=divDetailsContent.ClientID %>);
  }
  </script>

  <ScriptAction Script='update()' />
```